# How to use RouteBoxer.js for Google Map on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a route. Now, I want to find all nearby markets, for example, around that route. On web version, I use [RouteBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html) library successfully. The problem is I can't use it in Google Map on Android, because it is a javascript library.

What can I do now? How can I use that library on Android or do I have a workaround way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call javascript from your App in Android. You will need to use JS Evaluator for Android (JSEA).

Just do something like:

```
jsEvaluator.callFunction(new JsCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(final String result) {
    // get result here
  }
}, "functionName", "parameter 1", "parameter 2", 912, 101.3);
```

To call your javascript.

[image]

So, you can access the library that will allow you communicate your App with the RouteBoxer API. Just check it on [Github for JSEA](https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android). It should allow you to use RouteBoxer as usual.

[image]

Hence, you will call the route from your App.

Comment: Mind explaining how this can be achieved? I already tried [this](http://pastebin.com/dAPuPw35) but it doesn’t seem to work at all

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin - As AnhTriet already confirmed, the solution posted is correct. If you have some other question or troubleshooting that you may need some specific help, post it as a new question and you will have answers and suggestions from the StackOverflow Community.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use a Java port of the RouteBoxer.js available here: https://code.google.com/p/routeboxer-java/

Comment: Were you able to successfully integrate this Java port in an Android app?

Comment: @jesal yes, but with some slight hiccups - the box(...) algorithm (including buildgrid_ and mergeBoxesX_ and mergeBoxesY_) not perfect and the areas of the boxes are not consistent.  Vour usage may vary.

Comment: It’s also memory intensive so it mostly crashes for longer distances.