# Can I using Routeboxer Library on Google Map v2 for Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location-based-service, routeboxer

I have a project Android application and the project use web service as data provider. In android client, user can tracking place or search place along route. Can I using Route boxer Library on Google Map v2 for Android?
Considering Route boxer as library google map v3 for web development. 
I have try searching around solution for this but still confuse me.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060477/how-to-use-routeboxer-js-for-google-map-on-android) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/_zkgeoEemIs) should help you start on it. So... yes, you can use Route boxer with Google Maps.

Comment: i've read it but still confuse about use JSEA and connect it with google mapv3

Comment: Please explain more regarding what you are confused about. Here are some [tips regarding asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These should help you in getting across what you want and we'd be able to better help you.

Comment: i was confused whether use google map v3 and use web view or using google map v2 for android native?maybe have sample android application that uses routeboxer sorry for slow responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally can implement it to android by using google direction library download it from [here](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary)  and using routeboxer.java from [here](https://code.google.com/p/routeboxer-java/issues/detail?id=1)

Comment: i´m looking for how to implement routeboxer.java, can you please show some example code ?